# How do I change my model from the view in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a view that has this:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects">
    <input value="{{object.name}}" ngModel="object.name" ng-keyup="change(object)">
</div>
```

That fires this:

```
change: function(object) {
    console.log(object);
}
```

The above works, and it outputs the object to the console, but when I edit the name from the input above, it continues to update the original object and not the one with the newly edited name. How do I go about linking the input in the view to the object being modified so when change() is called, it logs the object with the updated name?

Comment: You'll need to use the property `ng-model` on the tag. In Angular, `camelCase` directives are changed into `kebab-case` properties. Also, you won't need a `value` property once you change that.

Comment: it should be `ng-model` not `ngModel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to Chris and PSL in the comments:

I needed to change `ngModel` to `ng-model`